# Exporting several maps with excel sheet using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, export, excel, mxd, jpg

I try to export 20 maps with this python code in ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop. Each map has excel sheet (not attribute table) in the layout view. The excel sheet file located in G:\Users\test\Downloads and imported from there:

```
import arcpy,os
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for num, mxd in enumerate((arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")),start = 1):
    print num,mxd
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxd)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mapdoc,
    r"G:\desktop\Project\ou\\" + os.path.basename(mapdoc.filePath).replace('.mxd','') +".jpg",resolution=196)
mapdoc.save()
del mxd
```

This code works fine, but when i insert object- excel sheet with those two options:

[image]

[image]

[image]

when i use the python code i get only white rectangle with no data table:

[image]

i red this , but didn't found any solution:

- [Attribute table added to layout is missing when mxd is exported to jpeg using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250498/attribute-table-added-to-layout-is-missing-when-mxd-is-exported-to-jpeg-using-ar/250509#250509)
- [Arcgis table and Excel sheet dynamic linking](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176379/arcgis-table-and-excel-sheet-dynamic-linking)

Comment: Where are you running your code from?  This looks like a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/250498/115

Comment: I add note to my question. i add excel sheet and not attribute table.

Comment: Try installing a virtual PDF printer, such as PDF Creator or Cute PDF, and print (via [PrintMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/printmap.htm)), not export.